# Proof of Lemma 6.3 in Carothers' Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

> **Lemma 6.3** *(Chapter 6 - Connectedness)*: Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $(M,d)$. If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, open
> sets in $E$, then there are disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ in $M$ such that $U= A \cap E$
> and $V = B \cap E$.

The proof roughly goes as follows (I haven't typed it out *exactly*, but I have captured all the important details) -

Since $U$ is open in $E$, for each $x\in U$, $\exists\epsilon_x > 0$ such that $E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x) \subset U$. Since $V$ is open in $E$, for each $y\in V$, $\exists\delta_y > 0$ such that $E\cap B(y,\delta_y) \subset V$. Since $U\cap V = \varnothing$, we also have $E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y,\delta_y) = \varnothing$.

Now, the author **claims that**:

> For every $x\in U$ and $y\in V$, $$B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}\right) \cap B\left(y,\frac{\delta_y}{2}\right) = \varnothing$$

Why is this true? I'm trying to show this in the following way. Suppose $z \in B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}\right) \cap B\left(y,\frac{\delta_y}{2}\right)$. So, $d(x,z) < \epsilon_x/2$ and $d(y,z) = \delta_y/2$. To show that the intersection is non-empty would amount to showing $d(x,z) < \epsilon_x/2$ and $d(y,z) = \delta_y/2$ cannot hold together. How do I do this?

> Thus, $$A = \bigcup_{x\in U} B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}\right) \text{ and } B = \bigcup_{y\in V} B\left(y,\frac{\delta_y}{2}\right)$$ work.

Why does this choice of $A, B$ work? All I need to show for this, is that $U = A\cap E$ and $V= B\cap E$ right? Is anything else needed to be done?

Thank you.

---

*Picture for Reference:*
[image]

---

*Attempting a Proof by Contradiction:*
As mentioned in an answer, $B(x,r/2)\subset B(x,r)$. Suppose $\exists x \in U, \exists y\in V$ for which $B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}\right) \cap B\left(y,\frac{\delta_y}{2}\right) \ne \varnothing$. Also, $$E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x) \subset U \implies E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x/2) \subset U$$ and
$$E\cap B(y,\delta_y) \subset V \implies E\cap B(y,\delta_y/2) \subset V$$
What's next? I'm not able to find a contradiction. $U\cap V = \varnothing \implies E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y,\delta_y) = \varnothing$, and I believe this is what we want to contradict.

Comment: I don't follow you... In lemma 6.3 $U$ and $V$ are supposed to be disjoint. Then later on you write $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$???

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net That was typing error, I have fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notations, suppose that:$\exists z\in E$ such that $z \in B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}\right) \cap B\left(y,\frac{\delta_y}{2}\right)$ 
It follows that: $d(x,z)\lt \epsilon_x/2$ and $d(y,z)\lt \delta_y/2\implies d(x,z)\lt \epsilon_x$ and $d(y,z)\lt \delta_y$ 
Therefore, $z\in B(x,\epsilon_x) $ and $z\in B(y, \delta_y)$ whence it follows that $z\in B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y, \delta_y) $, which is a contradiction as $E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y, \delta_y)=\phi$

Comment: Why choose $z\in E$? It's possible for $B(x,\epsilon_x/2) \cap B(y,\delta_y/2)$ to contains elements not from $E$, right? What if all elements in the intersection are *not from* $E$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Think about this:$B(x,\epsilon_x/2)\subset B(x,\epsilon_x) \implies B(x,\epsilon_x/2) \subset U \subset E$

Comment: That's where all the trouble lies, I believe. All this while I've been thinking $U\subset E$ is not a requirement?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Right. And one more thing U and V are open sets (in E). So there exists open ball centered at every $x\in U$ which lies completely within U, radius of the ball is $\epsilon_x$. If $x$ changes so will $\epsilon_x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

Remember that for any $r \gt 0$, $B(x, r/2) \subseteq B(x,r)$. Therefore any point that would belong to $$B\left(x,\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}\right) \cap B\left(y,\frac{\delta_y}{2}\right)$$ would also belong to
$$B\left(x,\epsilon_x\right) \cap B\left(y,\delta_y\right)$$ in contradiction with the initial hypothesis.

**Question 2**

Is a consequence of the previous point.

Comment: *Question 1*: We have $E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y,\delta_y) = \varnothing$, and not $B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y,\delta_y) = \varnothing$, right? So, where is the contradiction? Is it that $B(x,\epsilon_x/2) \cap B(y,\delta_y/2) \ne \varnothing \stackrel{??}{\implies}  E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x/2) \cap B(y,\delta_y/2) \ne \varnothing \implies E\cap B(x,\epsilon_x) \cap B(y,\delta_y) \ne \varnothing$? As the question mark suggests, I don't think the first implication always holds.